# What under \subsubsection?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

In a `\subsubsection`, I'm describing a software component, and I have to describe the classes it is composed of. I'm thinking to add some "titles" like "Class 1", "Class 2", but what's the best way to do this?

The simple way I know is to put a `\noindent \textbf{myTitle}`, is there a smarter way?

Thoses sub-titles don't go in the index, but it is important they are clearly distinguishable

Comment: Can I offer another suggestion? Maybe you could use a `description` environment to describe classes instead of going deeper in the sectioning levels.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard classes provide the additional sectioning commands `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` below the `\subsubsection` level. By default, these levels are unnumbered, aren't included in the table of contents and are typeset in "runin" style, i.e., without a vertical space between level title and following text.

For a general overwiew of sectioning commands, see section 2.7 of [lshort](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english).